# SQL Check Current time is between two DATETIME columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need to check whether the current time is between two datetime column values.

And I only need to check the time is between the range and I don't want to check the date.

I know how to check a date is exists between a daterange like below

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    Table1 T
WHERE 
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) BETWEEN T.StartDate AND T.EndDate
```

We have stored start date and end date as folllows..

```
StartDate - 1900-01-01 08:00:00.000
EndDate   - 1900-01-01 19:00:00.000
```

Is there something similar to this to check whether the time is exists in a date range?

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result

Comment: Hmm I don't understand your question. Isn't the example you've shown exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: The very same way you would do with date values, just using DATETIME columns instead.

Comment: whats wrong with the code provided?

Comment: I just want to check the time without the date

Comment: T.StartDate?  data format ex: dd/mm/yyyy ? please explain

Comment: Then how can be a TIME value between DATE values? How can be 12:54:53 between 2017-01-01 and 2017-05-01 ?

Comment: you can convert to time instead of casting to date..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you only want to check time

```
SELECT  *
FROM Table1 T
WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) BETWEEN cast(T.StartDate as TIME) AND cast(T.EndDate as TIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I guess

```
declare @d1 datetime ='20171220 10:00'
   , @d2 datetime = '20171220 12:00'
   , @t time ='11:00';
select 'Yes' where @t between cast(@d1 as time) and cast(@d2 as time);
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I tried like below

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T
WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) BETWEEN CAST(T.StartDate AS TIME) AND CAST(T.EndDateAS TIME)
```

Comment: if can ensure the date is always `1900-01-01` then you don't need to CAST() or CONVERT() StartDate to `TIME`. This will avoid unnecessary scan and faster

Answer (score -1):

CONVERT() to `TIME` and then back to `DATETIME` and compare

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE()))
      BETWEEN T.StartDate AND T.EndDate
```

Comment: StartDate = '01 jan 2017 17:54' and EndDate = '02 jan 2017 00:01' how this work?

Comment: the OP stated the date is '1900-01-01'