# How to query if a time is between two field values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query, range-query

How do I [search for documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html) that are between a start and end time?   For example, I want to query the following document using a time only like "18:33" or "21:32".  "18:33" would return the following document and "21:32" wouldn't.  I don't care about the date part nor the secs.

```js
{
  "my start time field": "2020-01-23T18:32:21.768Z",
  "my end time field": "2020-01-23T20:32:21.768Z"
}
```

I've reviewed: [Using the `range` query with `date` fields.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates) but I'm not sure how to only look at times.  Also, I want to see if a time is between two fields, not if a field is between two times.

---

Essentially, the Elasticsearch equivalent of `BETWEEN` for SQL Server.  [Like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902640/185123) except I don't want to use the current time but a variable.

```sql
DECLARE @blah datetime2 = GETDATE()

SELECT  *
FROM Table1 T
WHERE CAST(@blah AS TIME) 
      BETWEEN cast(T.StartDate as TIME) AND cast(T.EndDate as TIME)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion from the OP and the link he provided which adheres to the laws of stackoverflow I'm providing the second solution in here:

### Solution 2: Insert separate fields for hour minute as hh:mm

Note the format used which says [`hour_minute`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html). You can find the list of formats available under the aforementioned link.

Basically you re-ingest the documents with a separate field that would have `hour and minute values` and execute `range queries` to get what you want.

**Mapping:**

```
PUT my_time_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "start_time":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "hour_minute"
      },
      "end_time":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "hour_minute"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Document:**

```
POST my_time_index/_doc/1
{
  "start_time": "18:32",
  "end_time": "20:32"
}
```

**Query Request:**

```
POST my_time_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "start_time": {
              "gte": "18:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "end_time": {
              "lte": "21:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Don't store times in a datetime datatype based upon [this discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-filter-for-a-specific-time-range/105169/2).

> If you want to filter for the specific hour of the day, you would need to extract that into it's own field.

Via the [Kibana Dev Tools -> Console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/console-kibana.html)

Create some mock data:

```
POST between-research/_doc/1
{
  "my start hour": 0,
  "my end hour": 12
}

POST between-research/_doc/2
{
  "my start hour": 13,
  "my end hour": 23
}
```

Perform "between" search

```
POST between-research/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "my start hour": {
              "lte": 10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "my end hour": {
              "gte": 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1: Existing Date Format

Without changing and ingesting your hours and minutes separately, I've come up with the below solution and I don't think you would be happy with the way ES provides you the solution, but it certainly works.

I've created a sample mapping, document, the query and response based on the data you've provided.

**Mapping:**

```
PUT my_date_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "start_time":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
      },
      "end_time":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Documents:**

```
POST my_date_index/_doc/1
{
  "start_time": "2020-01-23T18:32:21.768Z",
  "end_time": "2020-01-23T20:32:21.768Z"
}

POST my_date_index/_doc/2
{
  "start_time": "2020-01-23T19:32:21.768Z",
  "end_time": "2020-01-23T20:32:21.768Z"
}

POST my_date_index/_doc/3
{
  "start_time": "2020-01-23T21:32:21.768Z",
  "end_time": "2020-01-23T22:32:21.768Z"
}
```

**Query Request:**

```
POST my_date_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                ZonedDateTime zstart_time = doc['start_time'].value;
                int zstart_hour = zstart_time.getHour();
                int zstart_minute = zstart_time.getMinute();
                int zstart_total_minutes = zstart_hour * 60 + zstart_minute;

                ZonedDateTime zend_time = doc['end_time'].value;
                int zend_hour = zend_time.getHour();
                int zend_minute = zend_time.getMinute();
                int zend_total_minutes = zend_hour * 60 + zend_minute;

                int my_input_total_minutes = params.my_input_hour * 60 + params.my_input_minute;

                if(zstart_total_minutes <= my_input_total_minutes && zend_total_minutes >= my_input_total_minutes){
                  return true;
                }

                return false;

              """,
              "params": {
                "my_input_hour": 20,
                "my_input_minute": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Basically

- calculate number of minutes from `start_date`
- calculate number of minutes from `end_date`
- calculate number of minutes from `params.my_input_hour` & `params.my_input_minute`
- execute the logic in if condition as `start_date <= input <= end_date` using the minutes of all the three values and return the documents accordingly.

**Response:**

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_time_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "start_time" : "18:32",
          "end_time" : "20:32"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Do test them thoroughly for performance issues when it comes to solution 1 as [script queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) generally hit performances, however they come in handy if you have no option.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Should you post 2 separate solutions?  Then the community can upvote one over the other.  Then the next person can have an easier time.   to solution 2!

Comment: Hi @OpsterESNinja-Kamal - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269546/185123

Comment: Hi Opster - I'd like to accept solution 2 as the answer, how you feel about separating them?

Comment: @spottedmahn Thank you so much for that link and following conventions of stackoverflow. It was a pleasure helping you as it helped me learn something new. I've never knew I could add multiple answers. Thank you once again!!